# Creating thumbnail images in IronPython using CLR. Passing delegate troubles

Tags: image, clr, ironpython

I am trying to create a thumbnail image using IronPython utilising the Common Language Runtime.

Coming from a Visual Basic background I am struggling with the concept of passing a delegated function to the CLR from within IronPython.

Below is my coding:

```
import os
import clr

# contains Image definition
clr.AddReference('System.Drawing')
from System.Drawing import Image

# contains Action and Func for delegation
clr.AddReference('System.Core')
from System import Func

# open image filename
objImageA = Image.FromFile('a.jpg')

# delegated function
def ImageAbortDelegate():
    return False


objThumbImageAbort = Func[objImageA.GetThumbnailAbort](ImageAbortDelegate)

# for this example reduce image by 10 percent
intHeight = objImageA.Height / 10
intWidth = objImageA.Width / 10

# why is this failing?
objThumbImageA = objImageA.GetThumbnailImage(intHeight, intWidth, objThumbAbort, 0)
# gives error message TypeError: expected GetThumbnailImageAbort, got Func[GetThumbnailImageAbort]
```

Answer (score 1):

That works perfectly. Thank you.

For a better understanding, would you be able to explain what is happening with the ThumbnailImageAbort() function.

Comment: `GetThumbnailImageAbort` creates the delegate, that's why there is no need to wrap it in `Func`.

Answer (score 0):

To create an instance of `GetImageThumbailAbort`, all you need is `objImageA.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ImageAbortDelegate)`. When you try to create the thumbnail image you have to pass a `IntPtr` type, not just a regular integer, so you'll need to import the type. To do that import you will need `from System import IntPtr`. When you go to create the thumbnail in the end, you should have something like `objThumbImageA = objImageA.GetThumbnailImage(intHeight, intWidth, objThumbAbort, IntPtr(0))`.